# Get Content From URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've started a small project that I planned on just using PHP for, but I've ended up needing to integrate javascript with.

I was hoping someone could confirm if this is possible to do with javascript.

Basically I need to get the content from a specific URL, we'll call it:

```
http://example.com/api/API-DETAILS
```

That URL will respond with a number.  If the number is over `0`, then I want to simply run a PHP file, we'll call it:

```
http://website.com/file.php?data=test&more=example
```

If the number isn't above `0`, nothing else needs to be done.

Is this something that could easily be done in Javascript?

Comment: Yes I think so, you'll call the first url using `AJAX` and depending on the result, you will use `location` to redirect with js to the new url or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XHR ([XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)):

```
function reqListener () {
  if (this.status==200)
{
      if(this.responseText !== '0') {
         location="http://website.com/file.php?data=test&more=example";
      }
}
  else
      throw new Error(this.statusText);

}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://example.com/api/API-DETAILS");
oReq.send();
```